# How do we filter the entities which is not start with "msdn" using MSDynamics Web API

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I want to get all entities which are the name not start the prefix as 'msdn' from ms dynamics.
I tried the below APIs, got the error.

```
GET /api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions?$select=LogicalName&$filter=not startswith(LogicalName,%27msdn%27)
```

Response :

```json
{  
"error":
      {"code":"0x0",
       "message":"The \"startswith\" function isn't supported for Metadata Entities."
       }
}
```

I referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/query-data-web-api#standard-query-functions

Comment: You may have to retrieve them all and filter after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked that in one of my environment as well. What you require is not possible.

You will have to go 2 steps.

Retrieve all entities and then filter them out in your local program may it be JavaScript/C# or Json filtering/Power automate or something.

Answer (score 0):

As fetching several thousands records for getting ten of them is not very good approach,  I went with own API object definition, where I include the NOT filter either in columnDataFilter:

`DataItemTableFilter = "Interaction Template Code" = filter('<>THIS_NOT_INCLUDED*');`

Or in onBeforeOpen trigger

```
trigger OnBeforeOpen()
    begin
        currQuery.SETFILTER(interactionTemplateCode, <>THIS_NOT_INCLUDED*');
    end;
```

In my case the `THIS_NOT_INCLUDED` is fixed, so it is possible.